# Is my method wrong for solving this integration question?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I wish to solve this question
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{y}{1+xy}\ dx\ dy$$

I take $1 + xy = t$ *i.e.* $y\ dx = dy$

New Limits = $1$ to $1 + y$.

Expression becomes $\int -1/2\sqrt{t}$.

Still getting wrong answer after second integration :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Where is the square root coming from?

Comment: This is not how you perform a change of variable in the multivariate case. You need a Jacobian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inside integral is $\int_1^{1+y}\frac  1 t dt=\ln t|_1^{1+y}=\ln (1+y)$ and the answer is $\int_0^{1} \ln (1+y)dy=[(1+y)\ln (1+y)-(1+y)]|_0^{1}=2\ln 2 -1$.

Comment: Thank you sir got my mistake :)